# Iterate and append a dict of each object from an array to new array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python how do you iterate and append a dict of each object from an array into a new array (for serializing the data to return json in a GET request)? The existing iteration is returning duplicates of the last object in the array as shown in current results below and not printing the intended results below.

**Note:**

*I am using SQLAlchemy's .get.all() to get the initial messages and they serve as not JSON serializable, I am trying to stay away from libraries such as Marshmallow. Flask `.jsonify(response)` and `json.dumps(response)` throw errors.*

```
message = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'message': the first message,
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'message': the second message
        }
    ]

response = []
row_data = {}

for message in messages:
    for k, v in message.items():
        row_data[k] = str(v)
    response.append(row_data)
print(response)
```

current response:

```
[
    {
        'id': '2',
        'message': 'the second message',
    },
    {
        'id': '2',
        'message': 'the second message'
    }
]
```

intended response:

```
[
    {
        'id': '1',
        'message': 'the first message',
    },
    {
        'id': '2',
        'message': 'the second message'
    }
]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just passing the message to `json.dumps()`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I am using `SQLAlchemy`'s `.get.all()` to get the initial messages and they serve as not JSON serializable, I am trying to stay away from libraries such as Marshmallow.

Comment: `response = [{k:str(v) for k,v in msg.items()} for msg in message]` may give you want you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are not breaking the connection from `row_data` to the dictionary you append to `response`.

Because of this, after the first iteration, `row_data` still points to the same dictionary that is the first element in the `response` list. You then modify the values stored in the dictionary, and append it a second time. This modification changes the dictionary, but because you have two references to the same dict, you think that you're getting two copies of the data -- you're not.

This problem is similar to the [**Mutable Default Argument**](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) problem, in that a single collection item is being re-used when it shouldn't be.

As a solution, I would suggest moving the initializer inside your loop. This will create a new dictionary each time:

```
for message in messages:
    row_data = {}
    for k, v in message.items():
        row_data[k] = str(v)
    response.append(row_data)
```

A better solution would be to use a different mechanism to create the dictionary. All you are doing is copying the items, so consider using the `dict.copy()` method, or the `dict()` builder.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem with the current code/algorithm

The problem with this particular code is that it ends up overwriting the content of `row_data`, and append two copies of essentially the same memory location in the list, hence the same value as the last item. What you would do, is to reset `row_data` at every `message`, like this:

```
messages = [    
        {
            'id': 1,
            'message': 'the first message',
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'message': 'the second message'
        }
    ]

response = []

for message in messages:
    row_data = {}    # create new empty dict

    for k, v in message.items():  # fill the dict with key->value
        row_data[k] = str(v)

    response.append(row_data)    # append the new item to the list

print(response)
```

### Are there better ways?

> As you added information about it not being JSON serializable, this might not apply directly. Leaving this portion as it might help someone in the future.

Of course, especially because what you are doing is dealing with JSON data, which is natively handled in Python with the `json` library. Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you should be looking at methods in that library.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to read the input from `message` and get an output with keys and values in strings.

```
response = [{k:str(v) for k,v in msg.items()} for msg in message]
```

This will give you the following output:

```
[{'id': '1', 'message': 'the first message'}, {'id': '2', 'message': 'the second message'}]
```

Looks like this is what you are trying to do with the two for loops and append statement.

Answer (score 0):

You will understand what went wrong if you `print(row_data)` after your loop:

```
{
    'id': 2,
    'message': 'the second message'
}
```

There are only ever two keys in `row_data`: `'id'` and `'message'`, which you overwrite in your loop. When you append `row_data` to your `response` `list` you add only the reference to `row_data`, which, as you see above, only contains reference two the second message.

There is an easy workaround however. You don't need the inner loop:

```
messages = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'message': 'the first message',
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'message': 'the second message'
    }
]

response = []
row_data = {}

for message in messages:
    response.append(message)
print(response)
```

Although, as pointed out already, you don't need loops at all in this case and should be able to dump the `messages` as is.

Answer (score 0):

Your array already contains dictionaries, so you can simply use the `JSON` module.

```
import json
output_string = json.dumps(messages)
```